# Set the QGIS display to show decimal degrees?

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS 2.6.1 Brighton. I am trying to set the `CRS` for the project to display `Decimal Degrees`, where it is defaulting to `Feet`. I can change it in the Properties Dialog, but it does not change it, it is just staying on `Feet`. How do I change it?

Edit: this layer was imported from a shapefile where it was internally set to `Feet`. I was able to get the vendor to supply one with `Decimal Degrees` so my problem is gone. Still would love to know if there was a way to do it myself from within `QGIS`.

Comment: I just tried the same thing using a shapefile in State Plane Feet and with the project properties > Canvas Units > Degree option and it worked just fine...

Comment: @mapBaker I don't have a `Canvas` selector in `Project Properties` - Thanks

Comment: Resurrecting this one. Anyone know how to do it in 3.2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Within the Project Properties > General dialogue box, you should have an option to set the Canvas Units:

[image]

However: it seems for using Decimal Degrees as your display units, your map must be projected 'on the fly' to WGS 84 / 4326:

[image]

Keeping your map in your original coordinates seems to limit the use of decimal degrees, while you can still use DMS, Degrees Minutes, etc.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Thanks though.

Comment: @DonA did you ever get this to work?

Comment: No, but i have moved on. I don't use QGIS currently.

Answer (score 3):

(I am not allowed to comment that's why I am writing it here.)

I had the same problem in QGIS 3.2.3 as DonA had. The solution of DPSSpatial did not work for me at first. Only when I closed QGIS, started it again with a new project, and then set the menu to the following (which is basically the same as DPSSpatial described):

[image]

Then I loaded the data I wanted it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you load the data into QGIS, and the units are in feet, you better leave that untouched.

You can use `Rightclick -> Save As ...` to another filename and choose `EPSG:4326` as new CRS for that. Add the new layer to the canvas, and delete the old one.

You can use `Rightclick -> Set Project CRS from Layer`to get the coordinates displayed in the layers units.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it once, been busy, did not work - but will try it some more when I can.

Answer (score -1):

I think quickfinder plugin is the best as you can have customer search field defined. Also you can have OSM place search result including administrative boundry.

Comment: How does this answer the question?