# Correct way to use WGS84 (lat/long degrees) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

1. I created new project in QGIS (v3.2.1)
2. Added a *OSM Standard* layer with *QuickMapServices* plugin. Current CRS is EPSG:3857

   [image]
3. Now I want to use map in degree units. As far as I understand I need to convert CRS to WGS 84. So I pressed the button:
   [image]
4. **Project Properties | CRS** dialog box appeared. I filtered CRS by string `'84'`. There were two potential candidate geographic coordinate systems in that list: EPSG:4326 and IGNF:WGS84G
   [image]
5. It looks like both of them do not fit because of the map distorted in both cases. The original view (EPSG:3857) was following:
   [image]
   After changing to CRS to EPSG:4326 it became look like:
   [image]

How to solve my problem with degree coordinate systems?

---

The following is the image of layer context-menu:
[image]
It has not `Save as` element.

Comment: What do you mean by distorted map? World looks like that when it is presented in "plate carrée" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection

Comment: @user30184: Thank you for the question. I added images to explain.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. There are different ways to present a round world as flat and each of them is introducing distortion.

Comment: If you want to keep the map in EPSG:3857 but to see the coordinates in degrees, change the project setting as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131838/how-to-set-the-qgis-display-to-show-decimal-degrees. About the different projections and their distortions see the images  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection.

Comment: Thank you. It helps. Do you mind to make your comment an answer I could upvote?

Answer (score 3):

Save your data to a new file and switch CRS to EPSG:4326 when saving. Naturally there will be some distortion, as it is bound to be when you try to press a ball's surface to a plane.

Addition on specified question: Changing the displayed coordinates at the bottom of the screen as follows: ´Project -> project properties -> general (topmost tab) -> displayed coordinates (or similar, third triangle in the tab)´ - at least in QGis 2.18 - maybe in 3.2 it's a bit different, but probably not much.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I didn't suggested to choose CRS when I saving the data. Did you mean: `menu > Project > Save as`?

Comment: Rightclick the layer and choose ´save as´ there.

Comment: There is not `Save as` in context menu for layer of my QGIS version (3.2.1). I have added an update with image of my context menu for layer.

Comment: You cannot "save as" QuickMapServices layers.

Comment: Didn't see the QuickMap-bit, sorry. Still, when displaying an image in a CRS it wasn't saved with, it will be distorted. Nothing you can do about it. So, do you really have to work using EPSG 4326?

Comment: Actually, I do not need  EPSG 4326. I need to see decimal degrees as a map unit.

Comment: Well, that's easy: ´Project -> project properties -> general (topmost tab) -> displayed coordinates (or similar, third triangle in the tab)´ - at least in QGis 2.18 - maybe in 3.2 it's a bit different, but probably not much.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind to make your comment an answer I could upvote?

Comment: Edited the answer.