# Issue displaying UTM coordinates in QGIS 3.6.1

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am having trouble properly displaying my .shp layers in UTM (QGIS 3.6.1). Whatever I do, the coordinates always display as lat/ long, and measurements are way out. I have re-saved all my .shp layers using the CRS GDA94 MGA zone 54, as well as setting my project CRS to GDA94 MGA zone 54, too.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This migh get you going in the right direction: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131838/set-the-qgis-display-to-show-decimal-degrees